# Model from PartialView to Controller returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a PartialView that recibes a Model ID and then when you click on the link sends the Model ID to the Controller. My problem was that there were 2 ways to send data from View to Controller but just only one worked for me. What's the reason why?

This worked perfectly for me

```html
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Dictionary" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-wordId="@Model"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
```

This one didn't work

```html
<a type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="@Url.Action("Edit/" + Model)"><i class="far fa-list-alt"></i></a>
```

My question is why the last one didn't work and returned null if I am passing the Model ID to the URL

This is my full PartialView that receives a Model ID and works

```html
@model int

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<td style="width:150px">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Dictionary" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-wordId="@Model"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
    </div>
</td>
```

And this is my Controller Function that recibes the data

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? wordId)
{
    if(wordId == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var word = await _db.Dictionaries.FindAsync(wordId);
    if(word == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return View(word);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Url.Action` overload you are using takes in an action name and you are passing something like `/Edit/4` to it. You need to use the proper overload of the `Url.Action` method that allows you to specify route values.

It would look something like the following:

```html
<a type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="@Url.Action("Edit/" + Model)"><i class="far fa-list-alt"></i></a>
```

to

```html
<a type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { wordId = Model } )"><i class="far fa-list-alt"></i></a>`
```

As a side note, your `Edit` action takes a nullable `wordId` which doesn't make much sense to me. Generally, if you're editing something then it has already been created and should always have an `id`. The only case I can think of where this makes sense is if the `Edit` action actually handles creating data as well as editing data in which case that would be perfectly valid.

Comment: To add on, I prefer to use `@Url.Action("Edit", new { Model } )` over `@Url.Action("Edit/" + Model)` if you use option 1 and rename the parameter in your action. Using this method is much easier to maintain and scale if you ever have to add multiple values to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your main question, the reason your 1st anchor is working is because the args are correct. 
For example:

```html
<a asp-controller="Dictionary" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-wordId="1">Your link</a>
```

is equivalent to:

```html
<a href="/Dictionary/Edit/1"></a>
```

That works!

The second will not work because you are misusing `Url.Action`, the method you are using is this `Url.Action("Action")`

```
Url.Action("Edit/" + Model) or  Url.Action("Edit/1")
```

is searching for an action named: "Edit/1", which in your case will not be found.

so in your 2nd not working example

```html
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit/" + Model)">Your Link</a>
```

is equivalent to:

```html
<a href="null" />
```

In your case you should be using this in your anchor:

```
Url.Action("Edit", "Dictionary", new { id = @Model })
```

is equivalent to 
    /Dictionary/Edit/1

so:

```html
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Dictionary", new { id = Model })">Your link</a>
```